# Why doesn't my price string show in the application

Tags: java, swing

So I'm making a simple little program that will calculate the price of pizza when ordered. The pizza can come in small, medium, or large, and can come with 2 toppings for extra cost (pepperoni $1.25 and mushrooms $1.10). I created my total variable and put the costs into the program to be calculated but I'm getting a blank on my program where I expected the total to be. Any ideas?

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class Test extends JFrame
{
    double total = 0;
    String totalPrint="$" + Double.toString(total);

   public Test()
   {  



      sampleField = new JLabel(totalPrint);
      add(sampleField, BorderLayout.CENTER);


      class ChoiceListener implements ActionListener
      {  
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
         {  
            setSampleFont();
         }
      }

      listener = new ChoiceListener();

      createControlPanel();
      setSampleFont();
      setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
   }


   public void createControlPanel()
   {
      JPanel sizeGroupPanel = createCheckBoxes();
      JPanel styleGroupPanel = createRadioButtons();

      JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
      controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

      controlPanel.add(sizeGroupPanel);
      controlPanel.add(styleGroupPanel);

      add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   public JPanel createCheckBoxes()
   {
      pCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
      pCheckBox.addActionListener(listener);

      mCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Mushrooms");
      mCheckBox.addActionListener(listener);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(pCheckBox);
      panel.add(mCheckBox);
      panel.setBorder
         (new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Toppings"));

      return panel;
   }

   public JPanel createRadioButtons()
   {
      smallButton = new JRadioButton("Small");
      smallButton.addActionListener(listener);

      mediumButton = new JRadioButton("Medium");
      mediumButton.addActionListener(listener);

      largeButton = new JRadioButton("Large");
      largeButton.addActionListener(listener);
      largeButton.setSelected(true);

      ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
      group.add(smallButton);
      group.add(mediumButton);
      group.add(largeButton);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(smallButton);
      panel.add(mediumButton);
      panel.add(largeButton);
      panel.setBorder
            (new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Size"));

      return panel;
   }

   public void setSampleFont()
   {  

      if (pCheckBox.isSelected()) 
         total = total + 1.25;
      if (mCheckBox.isSelected()) 
         total = total + 1.10;

      double size = 0;
      double style = 0;

      final double SMALL_SIZE = 5.25;
      final double MEDIUM_SIZE = 7.55;
      final double LARGE_SIZE = 9.35;

      if (smallButton.isSelected()) 
         total = total + SMALL_SIZE;
      else if (mediumButton.isSelected()) 
          total = total + MEDIUM_SIZE;
      else if (largeButton.isSelected()) 
          total = total + LARGE_SIZE;

    sampleField.setFont(new Font(totalPrint, (int) style, (int) size));      
      sampleField.repaint();
   }

   private JLabel sampleField;
   private JCheckBox pCheckBox;
   private JCheckBox mCheckBox;
   private JRadioButton smallButton;
   private JRadioButton mediumButton;
   private JRadioButton largeButton;
   private ActionListener listener;

   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
}
```

Comment: can you paste a bigger program screenshot and only the code part you calculate the actual price?

Comment: See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots). (Tip - crop the white-space border).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no font named `"$" + Double.toString(total)` ... anywhere on the planet...

```
new Font(totalPrint, (int) style, (int) size)
```

The first parameter should be the name of the font you want to use, not it's text!

While where fixing this, a font size of `0` is going to produce a blank result at the same time.

**Updated with example**

[image]

```
public void setSampleFont() {

    if (pCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        total = total + 1.25;
    }
    if (mCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        total = total + 1.10;
    }

    // !! Supply a positive font size //
    double size = 64;
    // A nice style //
    double style = Font.BOLD;

    final double SMALL_SIZE = 5.25;
    final double MEDIUM_SIZE = 7.55;
    final double LARGE_SIZE = 9.35;

    if (smallButton.isSelected()) {
        total = total + SMALL_SIZE;
    } else if (mediumButton.isSelected()) {
        total = total + MEDIUM_SIZE;
    } else if (largeButton.isSelected()) {
        total = total + LARGE_SIZE;
    }

    // Use the JLabel's default font...
    Font font = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
    // Derive a new font at the required size and style...
    font = font.deriveFont((int)style, (int)size);

    sampleField.setText(totalPrint);
    sampleField.setFont(font);
//        sampleField.repaint();
}
```

On a side note.  You shouldn't need to do this EVERY time you want to update the price.  Set the font up once in the constructor...

Comment: Wow thats great! I really like the big bold numbers. But now they are just $0.0. Is my math wrong?

Comment: I think you're assuming that the `totalPrint` will automatically be updated when you change `total`, but it won't.  You need to update `totalPrint` as well.  In fact, I would simply use `sampleField.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total));` instead

Answer (score 2):

Along with font name being invalid, the font size should be greater than zero to be seen:

```
double size = 0; // hello?
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [NumberFormat's getCurrencyInstance method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html), as in the following code snippet:

```
    Double currencyAmount = new Double(9876543.21);
    Currency currentCurrency = Currency.getInstance(currentLocale);
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = 
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);

    System.out.println(
        currentLocale.getDisplayName() + ", " +
        currentCurrency.getDisplayName() + ": " +
        currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount));
```

Comment: While that's really good advice, that's not going to fix the OP's problem ;)